# Weird lighting issue where dimmer affects other lights sharing line voltage

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, led, dimmer-switch

I recently replaced a regular switch with a dimmer switch, and the dimmer switch seems to be affecting my other light that draws from the same line wire. When the dimmer is at max brightness everything is fine.

[image]

One switch controls 4 flush LED lights attached to the ceiling, the dimmer switch controls the 5 ball LEDs hanging from the ceiling.

[image]

When I dim the 5 ball LEDs, the other 4 lights dim or sometimes just behave weirdly (eg. turn off)

[image]

I attached a rough circuit diagram of how I wired it, what could be wrong? Does the dimmer LED force a certain voltage to be applied to other lights even if they are in parallel?

[image]

Comment: Did you change any wiring other than the connection to the dimmer?

Comment: Shut off the breaker, pull the switches out of the wall, **_do not disconnect any wiring_**, and take clear, focused pictures of how all the wiring _actually_ is connected, then [edit] them into you question.

Comment: These can't all be line hot wires or nothing in this diagram would have a closed circuit.  More detail or good photos would be needed.